# iPhone push: Firebase messaging sometimes user can receiver 3 same notification

Tags: iphone, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Backend send message once, but sometimes(or some device) user can receive 3 same notifications.

Does anyone understand this issue?

JS code:

```
  const messaging = await firebase.messaging()

  messaging.onBackgroundMessage((payload) => {
    console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message', payload);
    // Customize notification here
    const notificationTitle = payload.notification.title;
    const notificationOptions = {
      body: payload.notification.body,
      icon: 'icons/icon-192.png',
      badge: 'icons/icon-192.png'
    };

    self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
  });

  self.addEventListener('push', function (event) {
    console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Notification push received.', event);

    let data = event.data.text();
    data = JSON.parse(data);

    const title = data?.notification?.title;
    const body = data?.notification?.body;

    event.waitUntil(
      self.registration.showNotification(title, {
        body: body,
        icon: 'icons/icon-192.png',
        badge: 'icons/icon-192.png'
      })
    );
  });
```

user receive 1 notification